# sed replace all occurrences after character

Tags: linux, replace, sed

Using `sed` is there a way to replace all occurrences of a pattern on a line after a character?

So, for instance, replacing every space with an underscore after a full stop would transform this:

```
k i c k . t h e . b a b y
```

into this:

```
k i c k ._t_h_e_._b_a_b_y
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the dot between `the baby`? your example is not clear enough to illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, typo! See again

Comment: @NickBull everything after a `.` should have an `_` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(\.[^ ]*) /\1_/;ta' file
```

Replace spaces forward of the first `.` with `_`'s
or:

```
sed 's/\./&\n/;h;y/ /_/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Divide and conquer using the hold space.

Comment: That is beautiful, bravo

Answer (score 1):

A little long and I can't think of a shorter way, but works nice:

```
sed 'h ; s/[^.]*// ; s/ /_/g ; x ; s/\..*$// ; G ; s/\n//'
                       ^ ^ the pattern to replace
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F. -vOFS=. '{a=$1 ; $1="" ; gsub(" ","_") ; print a $0}'
                                       ^   ^ the pattern to replace
```